# merge couple of objects together with jq slurp add without overwrite duplicate key

Tags: object, ubuntu, jq, slurp

i have this two json files:
***ubuntubionic.json**:*

```
  {
    "ubuntu": {
      "os_ver": "bionic",
      "image": "abcdef",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "abc",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    }
  }
```

and **ubuntufocal.json**:

```
cat ubuntubionic.json
  {
    "ubuntu": {
      "os_ver": "focal",
      "image": "xxxx",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "xxxx",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    }
  }`
```

i want to merge these two files into 1 file to get output that looks like this:

```
{
    "ubuntu": {
      "os_ver": "focal",
      "image": "abcdef",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "abc",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    },
      "os_ver": "bionic",
      "image": "xxxx",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "xxxx",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"

  }
```

i tried jq -s add ubuntufocal.json ubuntubionic.json > all_os.json
but i'm getting that bionic is overwriting focal

```
cat all_os.json
{
  "ubuntu": {
    "os_ver": "bionic",
    "image": "xxxx",
    "image_tag": "3.33.3",
    "docker_compiler_image": "xxxx",
    "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
  }
}
```

how can this be solved? got totally lost in the JQ man page

Comment: Your desired output misses the array brackets `[…]` (if your intention is to merge the files into an array). Having them just right after each other, separated by a comma, is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

To just make it an array of the files' contents, you don't need `add` builtin as the `-s` flag already puts them together in an array

```sh
jq -s . ubuntubionic.json ubuntufocal.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "ubuntu": {
      "os_ver": "bionic",
      "image": "abcdef",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "abc",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    }
  },
  {
    "ubuntu": {
      "os_ver": "focal",
      "image": "xxxx",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "xxxx",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to pull out the `ubuntu` field name, and have each object's values (which happen to be objects as well) merged into an array, also use the `map` builtin:

```sh
jq -s '{ubuntu: map(.ubuntu)}' ubuntubionic.json ubuntufocal.json
```

or

```sh
jq -s '{ubuntu: map(add)}' ubuntubionic.json ubuntufocal.json
```

```json
{
  "ubuntu": [
    {
      "os_ver": "bionic",
      "image": "abcdef",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "abc",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    },
    {
      "os_ver": "focal",
      "image": "xxxx",
      "image_tag": "3.33.3",
      "docker_compiler_image": "xxxx",
      "image_compiler_tag": "4.44.4"
    }
  ]
}
```